# What is the code to check for the image file size when user chooses a file

Tags: javascript

What is the code to add to the below code to check for the image file size when user chooses a file, and to give an alert if the file size is bigger than 5MB? It should check for the file extension first, if the file extension is good, it should check for the size then.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        $("#ProductImage").change(function() {
            var f = this.value;
            var e = f.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
            var d = e.split(".").pop();
            if (d == "jpg" || d == "jpeg" || d == "png" || d == "gif" || d == "JPG" || d == "JPEG" || d == "PNG" || d == "GIF") {
                $("#file_name").val(e)
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid image file.")
            }
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

f.size will get the size of the file in bytes,
5242880 is 5mb in bytes

`if (f.size >= 5242880){
alert("Image file is too big)}`

More info about file.size > https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp

Comment: Zoe, where should I add your code into my code, I tried to add it and it did not work, can you show me the full code including my code? Please, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi pls check below code

```
function validateFileExtension(component,msg_id,msg,extns)
{
   var flag=0;
   with(component)
   {
      var ext=value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
      for(i=0;i<extns.length;i++)
      {
         if(ext==extns[i])
         {
            flag=0;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            flag=1;
         }
      }
      if(flag!=0)
      {
         document.getElementById(msg_id).innerHTML=msg;
         component.value="";
         component.style.backgroundColor="#eab1b1";
         component.style.border="thin solid #000000";
         component.focus();
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
}

function validateFileSize(component,maxSize,msg_id,msg)
{
   if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
   {
      if(component.value)
      {
         var oas=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
         var e=oas.getFile(component.value);
         var size=e.size;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if(component.files[0]!=undefined)
      {
         size = component.files[0].size;
      }
   }
   if(size!=undefined && size>maxSize)
   {
      document.getElementById(msg_id).innerHTML=msg;
      component.value="";
      component.style.backgroundColor="#eab1b1";
      component.style.border="thin solid #000000";
      component.focus();
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

also check below code

```
function checkFile(e) {

    /// get list of files
    var file_list = e.target.files;

    /// go through the list of files
    for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {

        var sFileName = file.name;
        var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
        var iFileSize = file.size;
        var iConvert = (file.size / 1048576).toFixed(2);

        /// OR together the accepted extensions and NOT it. Then OR the size cond.
        /// It's easier to see this way, but just a suggestion - no requirement.
        if (!(sFileExtension === "pdf" ||
              sFileExtension === "doc" ||
              sFileExtension === "docx") || iFileSize > 10485760) { /// 10 mb
            txt = "File type : " + sFileExtension + "\n\n";
            txt += "Size: " + iConvert + " MB \n\n";
            txt += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Atul, can you tell me what to add into my code, I do not want to introduce a totally new code and then try to debug it again, if you can incorporate your code into my code, that will be great.